# Tagging System in Hibernate with Annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tagging

I am trying to implement a tagging system in my database (MySQL V5.1.61), and then get that working in hibernate. Here are the relevant parts of my database:
[image: Schema]

And the data contained:
[image: user table]

[image: usertags]

[image: tags]

If I am doing this correctly, then 'nir' should have 3 tags associated with him, 'Food','Sorority', and 'Summer Internship'.

What I am having trouble with is implementing this relationship in hibernate (Using annotations):

The UserHibernate class (I'm using GWT so I need separate hibernate and DTO objects):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserHibernate implements Serializable{

    private int ID;
    //removed fields for brevity
    private Set<UserTagsHibernate> tags;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uID")
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tags
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<UserTagsHibernate> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    /**
     * @param tags the tags to set
     */
    public void setTags(Set<UserTagsHibernate> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }


}
```

The UserTagsHibernate Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usertags")
public class UserTagsHibernate {
    private int usertagsID;
    private UserHibernate user;
    private TagsHibernate tags;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="userforeignkey")
    public UserHibernate getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(UserHibernate userHibernate) {
        this.user = userHibernate;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tagforeignkey")
    public TagsHibernate getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(TagsHibernate tagsHibernate) {
        this.tags = tagsHibernate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "usertagsID")
    public int getUsertagsID() {
        return usertagsID;
    }
    public void setUsertagsID(int usertagsID) {
        this.usertagsID = usertagsID;
    }



}
```

The TagsHibernate Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class TagsHibernate {
    private int tagID;
    //removed for brevity

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tagID")
    public int getTagID() {
        return tagID;
    }

    public void setTagID(int tagID) {
        this.tagID = tagID;
    }

}
```

The problem that I am having is that when I try and retrieve a user, here 'nir', he shows up three times. I believe it is because he has 3 tags, so for some reason, when I issue the query "session.createCriteria(UserHibernate.class).add(Restrictions.eq("username", "nir")).list();" I get a list of length 3. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem pops up all the time when using the Criteria API...it's a known quirk.  The workarounds are either to use HQL instead or to add a transformer that filters out the duplicates like so:

```
session.createCriteria(UserHibernate.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("username", "nir"))
    .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list();
```

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more!  I really like the idea of the Criteria API, but I almost always end up using HQL instead because of this issue...it feels very hacky to have to remember to tell Hibernate to do the expected thing.